# Cyrillic sets CP 1048 conversion

Tags: unicode, cyrillic

I am using a printer which needs Cyrillic sets CP 1048 for printing Kazak and Russian language in text mode. How do we convert a text to CP 1048? CP 1048 is combined character set for Kazak and Russian languages. These languages come together in text files and this code page is available as a standard feature in the printer.

Comment: Clearer wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert text with some kind of text encoding converter.  Since it wasn't specified, I'll use a Python script.  Note this requires Python 3.5 or later.  That version first defined the `kz1048` [codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html).

Unicode string to [KZ-1048](https://www.iana.org/assignments/charset-reg/KZ-1048) encoding:

```
>>> 'Россия/Ресей'.encode('kz1048')
b'\xd0\xee\xf1\xf1\xe8\xff/\xd0\xe5\xf1\xe5\xe9'
```

Note in Python `b'\xd0\xee'` denotes a byte string containing the byte hexadecimal values `D0` and `EE`, which in [KZ-1048](https://www.iana.org/assignments/charset-reg/KZ-1048) represent `Р` and `о`.